# Tensor RT installation

Tags: nvidia, windows-11, tensorrt, tensorrt-python

I am trying to install Tensor Rt in windows 11. I have installed the necessary CUDA and CUDNN versions. But it says that the system is not supporting. So is tensor rt compatible with windows 11

I have tried installing it in possible ways but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Judging from [the support matrix](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/support-matrix/index.html) and [the installation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/install-guide/index.html#installing-zip) TensorRT is not fully supported on Windows 11.